# Pass by name and pass by value-result languages

Tags: programming-languages, parameter-passing

For my programming languages course, I'm trying to write some code snippets in languages that use pass by name or pass by value-result, preferably by default, but any language that even supports either of those would be fine. However, I haven't been able to find a single language that supports either of them. Does anyone know of a language that uses pass by value-result or pass by name? Preferably an imperative language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wikipedia article on evaluation strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) suggests that call-by-value-result is supported by fortran. Call-by-name is supported by algol 68.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to go this route.

Comment: **Algol 60** has call-by-value and call-by-name;  **Algol 68** has call-by-value and call-by-reference, and the programmer can manually adopt a call-by-copy-restore methodology.  Call-by-sharing looks a bit like call-by-reference (in the form of "proceduring"), but I'm not sure if they are actually the same in Algol68. The first version of Algol68 had call-by-need, but it was removed in Rev1;

Answer (score 1):

I think C Macros are Pass-by-name (**not** the C language itself of course). I don't know of any pass-by-value-result languages I'm afraid (to be honest I had to do a web search to find out what it means!).

Comment: I'm not sure C macros "count" for what I'm trying to do, but that's an interesting thought, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

if you pass a variable to a fortran function and you modify it there, you also modify it in the calling program:

psuedocode:

```
int j = 1
print j
addOne(j)
print j
```

would output:

```
1
2
```

Comment: I was always amused by the (really) old versions of Fortran that would let you call addOne(1) and modify the value of the constant 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think CLIPS expert system language would be pass by name.

Answer (score 0):

Both Java and C are pass-by-value language.

C is clearly a pass by value language.

Java is always been told "primitives are passed by value, objects are passed by reference". But since java object is a reference at anytime, so it is actually a reference value.

Java Language specification tells this:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#37472

Answer (score 0):

Algol supports pass-by-name as you can find some explanation [here](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/383/PassByName.html)

I was told that Ada supports pass-by-value/result but haven't tried out yet.