# Pass by Reference vs Pass by value result

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, programming-languages, pass-by-reference

Call by reference makes an alias of the formal parameter so every change of typical parameter affects also formal parameter, while pass-by value- result copies the result to the typical parameter and when the function returns, it copies the typical parameter to  formal.(Notice that call by value result is completely different to call by value).

Besides the implementation differences between these two  parameter passing  methods, it seems to me that the final result would be the same.

My question is does these two methods give the same results always or else could you give an example where these two methods return different results?

Comment: I think you misunderstood pass by value. Actually pass by value has not any affect on formal parameters.

Comment: @M.Amini ,Pass by value and value result are completely different things.

Comment: Now I think I learned something new :)

Comment: _when the function returns, it copies the typical parameter to formal_ - not in any language that I know.

Comment: @Henk Holterman ,it is used in fortran ,you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718140/pass-by-name-and-pass-by-value-result-languages  ,it is also also called copy in-copy out for this reason .You could also check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy  , were  it is mentioned as copy-restore or copy in-copy out or value return.

Comment: Well, that's right then because I don't know Fortran. But this is not what's in general called pass-by-value. You may want to be more precise about this.

Comment: @Henk Holterman ,I don't know fortran  too ,I learned parameter passing  in a university lesson (there are much more weird and strange methods from value result) ,I think I was clear that i asked value result and not value and that's the reason I described it in the beginning to be more clear ,also I stated that it is different from call by value in a comment above ...

Comment: @Henk Holterman, I understand that finally  it was a bit tricky because someone could understand the phrase "value result " as the result of call by value method ,I edited the post to be more clear...

Comment: You're still not terribly clear, what is call-by-result? Also, watch your spacing.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, you have right I ment to say call by value, i fixed it, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make a difference if the original variable were read during the course of the method. This could happen because:

- Two parameters were both provided using the same underlying variable
- The method invoked more code that read from the original variable
- Other threads are involved

Here's an example in C#:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int p = 10;
        Foo(ref p, () => Console.WriteLine(p));
    }

    static void Foo(ref int x, Action action)
    {
        action();
        x = 20;
        action();
    }
}
```

The output of this is

```
10
20
```

... because when `action()` is invoked the second time, the value of `p` has already changed to 20. If this used pass-by-result, the value of `p` would only change when `Foo` returned.